# Assumption in Itô-Tanaka formula

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

The Itô-Tanaka formula usually require that $f$ is the difference of two convex functions. But I do see this condition is used in the proof. I think the proof only needs the fact that $f$ is convex and use the integral representation of a convex function. Why is the reason of this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition that $f$ is the difference of two convex functions is more general than the condition $f$ is convex.  You only need to prove it for the case that $f$ is convex, though, because then the result follows from linearity.  So you prove the formula for when $f$ is convex, then immediately conclude the more general case for when $f$ is the difference of two convex functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think any linear combination (with non-negative coefficients) of convex functions is again convex. But $af-bg$ may not be convex for non-negative $a,b$ and convex $f,g$. So the assumption in this way is the most general one. Is it correct?

Comment: @mnmn1993 If I understand you correctly, that is correct.  If $f$ and $g$ are convex, $f-g$ need not be convex, so this is the most general case.